# Can I reset my firmware password manually or using third party tools?

Tags: password, efi, firmware

i forgot my firmware password on my macbook air 2013,i was tempting to replace my .efi file, but online articles says its too risks my machine can be corrupted forever. any idea on how i can solve this.

Answer (score 1):

From https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204455:

> If you can't remember your firmware password, schedule an in-person service appointment with an Apple Store or Apple Authorized Service Provider. Bring your Mac to the appointment, and bring your original receipt or invoice as proof of purchase.

Comment: i’ve already done that and advisors told me there’s no no AASP available in my region, and taking a plane to country where apple service providers are in is not a good idea! Am wondering if there’s like a technical way of doing that like flashing PRAM or downgrading the UEFI ?

Comment: @james Firmware password are often used as a kind of anti-theft measure, so I doubt it will be easy to work around one. But let's see whether somebody knows of a way.